# Integration and kth derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $f_{0}$ be continuous on $[0, b]$. For $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$ define
$$
f_{k}(x)=\frac{1}{k !} \int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^{k} f_{0}(t) d t.
$$

Show that for every $k$, the $k$th derivative of $f_{k}$ exists and equals to $f_0$.

It seems that induction will help a lot with this problem. However, my main challenge was to derive the base case $k = 1$, wherein the inductive hypothesis was fairly manageable to deal with using the FTC and Integration by Parts, though I would like to see any suggestions about this part as well.

Note: For the basis case, I only found that the first derivative of function $f_1(x)$ is $$\int_{0}^{x}f_{0}(t)dt.$$ How could this possibly be equal to the function $f_0(t)$?

Comment: Strange, plugging in $x$ for $t$ as per the FTC appears to get $f_1'=0$, unless I am reading this wrong due to just waking up

Comment: I guess plugging in the values for $x$ is not that important compared to what one needs for the FTC computations. In fact, the most strange thing is obtaining the integral of $f_0(x)$ instead of itself for the first derivative of $f_1(x)$. I guess further suggestions could be very beneficial to lay upon more advanced features of this property. @Alan

Comment: Could anyone suggest some further ideas on how one could possibly proceed with these types of recursive integrals?